# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Seasoned Advice breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  7         14
Users destroyed                                  26          0
Users deleted                                     2          0
Users contacted                                  21          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           224      1,670
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue                7        120
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue         38      1,046
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue               10      1,439
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                20      2,897
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue               19        920
Tags merged                                       1          0
Tag synonyms proposed                             1          2
Tag synonyms created                              1          0
Questions reopened                               23          0
Questions protected                               5         86
Questions migrated                               13          0
Questions merged                                  5          0
Questions flagged⁴                                9        587
Questions closed                                497        133
Question flags handled⁴                         170        426
Posts unlocked                                    0          2
Posts undeleted                                  33         21
Posts locked                                      4        109
Posts deleted⁵                                1,121        740
Posts bumped                                      0        360
Escalations to the CM team                        1          0
Comments undeleted                               37          0
Comments flagged                                  2      1,146
Comments deleted⁶                             1,720      1,178
Comment flags handled                           481        667
Answers flagged                                 100      2,081
Answer flags handled                          1,959        222
All comments on a post moved to chat              9          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...